# android - add one xml layout in other xml layout

Tags: android

I have two XML layouts declared in the res/layout folder one contains the generic template and the other contains the views specific to a particular screen. I want to add the second xml layout to the first one i.e. the generic one. As both of these layouts are declared as XML, I am not able to add one to other. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using a [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) and inflating your specific view and adding it to a ViewGroup or FrameLayout?

Answer (score 16):

I may not be understanding it correctly.  But it might be a lot easier to use the `<include layout="@layout/yourlayouthere" />` method to simply embed using just XML notation.  I use this method to build a bunch of little parts and then pull them together in my main layout using the inlcude statement.

Comment: there is any method available if button clicked then this **include** tag enable.